# Is there a way to link Apex Test Results to MTM

Tags: automated-testing, regression-testing, mtm

I am executing automated tests through Salesforce's Apex Test Execution, and was wondering if there was a way to connect these test results to work items in Microsoft Test Manager?

Comment: or linking to TFS in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a prebuilt connection tool, so you'd need to work with the Salesforce and Team Foundation Server APIs.

This can be done, but it will take some programming.

Comment: thanks, do you know where I might find some documentation to point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: The API for TFS is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465178.aspx